# pandas dropna() only if in first row NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following

```
df = [[1,'NaN',3],[4,5,'Nan'],[7,8,9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

and I would like to remove all columns *that have in their first row* a NaN value.

So the output should be:

```
df = [[1,3],[4,'Nan'],[7,9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

So in this case, only the second column is removed since the first element was a NaN value.
Hence, dropna() is based on a condition.. any idea how to handle this? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values are `np.nan` and not string `NaN`(*else replace them*), you can do:

**Input:**

```
df = [[1,np.nan,3],[4,5,np.nan],[7,8,9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

---

**Solution:**

```
df.loc[:,df.iloc[0].notna()] #assign back to your desired variable

   0    2
0  1  3.0
1  4  NaN
2  7  9.0
```